# via 'addTab' added tab not clickable or activateable

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have these jquery tabs, when I add a new tab dynamically on page it is selected. 
Now the problem is that dynamically/onpage added tabs cant get selected again.

For Example: there is one tab. I add a new tab and it gets selected now i can open the first tab but I cannot open the second tab again.

Here is the jscode
        
    $(function() {

```
//When page loads...
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});

    //Addtab
        var fields = $("ul.tabs li").length;
    $("a.pekle").click(function() {fields += 1;
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $("ul.tabs").append('<li class="active"><a href="#tab'+fields+'">'+fields+'. Parca</a></li>').hide().fadeIn(500);
        $("div.tab_container").append('<div id="tab'+fields+'" class="tab_content"> Tab'+fields+'</div>');
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    $("#tab"+fields).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;});
    //EndAddtab
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a class="pekle" onClick="addTab()">+ Parca Ekle</a>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Parca 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">blabala</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things wrong here. First you `tab_container`  wasn't included in your example, i'm assuming you want to wrap it around the content `div's` like so.

```
<a class="pekle" onClick="addTab()">+ Parca Ekle</a>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Parca 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">blabala</div>
<div>​
```

Second, because you are adding the tabs dynamically, you will need to delegate the click handler by using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler instead of click.

> If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and
>   attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or,
>   use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

```
$("ul.tabs").on('click', 'li', function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

**[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/62DAy/1/)**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I cant thank you enough that worked like a charm, Im sorry i cant vote up but if i could i wouldve votedup your answer +999!

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation it says